# Core-Plot messed up scatterplot - What's wrong here?

Tags: ios, graph, plot, core-plot

Using Core-Plot for a scatterplot in an iOS project here, and I suddenly started experiencing the weirdest thing.

There are 5 plots added to this graph, each with a separate color (I've checked again and again with allPlots). For whatever reason there seem to be "ghost" plots on it, and not all records are being shown.

[image: Core-Plot scatterplot with weird issues]

Anybody have any idea what might be wrong here? This was working perfectly before. Been trying for the last 2 hours to figure out what is wrong, but everything I check seem correct.

Comment: Input is same as before? Or different iOS version?

Comment: Had a messed up C array in doublesForPlot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out I was returning a messed up C array in doublesForPlot that caused this.